# CSS image inside another image with div

Tags: html, css

I've created a text and I want it to be inside an image (no repeat). And I want that to be placed inside another image in the center, all four side and not just both side. Here's the code. It's like background bigger image (500x500), foreground image (250x250) and text on top the foreground image with opacity.

CSS:

```
div.background
{
    width:500px; 
    height:500px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:LimeGreen;
}

div.box
{
    margin:5px;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:white;
    border:5px dotted white;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="background">
        <div class="box">
            <p>image inside another image</p>
        <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you close the "box" class with a </div> instead of a <br /> ?

Comment: Isn't exactly what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/nvSyy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eE7zV/1/